# c2.createTrackbar изменение параметров при движении ползунков

Tags: python, opencv

В реальном времени у меня отображается окно с видеокамерой. Я хочу, чтобы ползунками можно было менять значение функции **cv2.threshold** (в методе threshold), однако не понимаю как правильно это сделать. Ниже пример программы, в которой эти ползунки работают некорректно. Остальное же работает как надо. Менять хочу переменные **thr1** и **thr2**.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import easyocr


def threshold(gray, thr1, thr2):
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thr1, thr2, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    return thresh


def text_recognition_en(file_path):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(["en"])
    result = reader.readtext(file_path, detail=0, paragraph=True)
    return result


def save_text_en(image_to_scan, count_en):
    result = text_recognition_en(image_to_scan)
    with open("result_en" + str(count_en) + ".txt", "w") as file:
        for line in result:
            file.write(f"{line}\n\n")
    file.close()


def text_recognition_ru(file_path):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(["ru"])
    result = reader.readtext(file_path, detail=0, paragraph=True)
    return result


def save_text_ru(image_to_scan, count_ru):
    result = text_recognition_ru(image_to_scan)
    with open("result_ru" + str(count_ru) + ".txt", "w") as file:
        for line in result:
            file.write(f"{line}\n\n")
    file.close()


def main():
    root_window = "main";
    cv2.namedWindow(root_window)

    # Параметры Threshold
    thr1 = 0
    thr2 = 255

    # Слайдеры для изменения параметров Threshold
    cv2.createTrackbar('threshold par 1', root_window, thr1, 255, threshold)
    cv2.setTrackbarPos('threshold par 1', root_window, 0)
    cv2.createTrackbar('threshold par 2', root_window, thr2, 255, threshold)
    cv2.setTrackbarPos('threshold par 2', root_window, 255)

    # Все параметры камеры
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)  # Частота кадров
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)  # Ширина кадров в видеопотоке.
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)  # Высота кадров в видеопотоке.

    # img / gray / thresh / cnts / img
    count_ru = 1  # Нумерация картинок и текстов
    count_en = 1

    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thresh = threshold(gray, thr1, thr2)

        # Поиск контуров и сортировка
        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

        # Поиск рамки
        for c in cnts:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            ROI = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            break

        cv2.imshow(root_window, thresh)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('e'):
            cv2.imwrite('image_en' + str(count_en) + '.jpg', ROI)
            image_to_scan = 'image_en' + str(count_en) + '.jpg'
            #cv2.imwrite('image_en_thresh' + str(count_en) + '.jpg', thresh)
            save_text_en(image_to_scan, count_en)
            count_en += 1

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('r'):
            cv2.imwrite('image_ru' + str(count_ru) + '.jpg', ROI)
            image_to_scan = 'image_ru' + str(count_ru) + '.jpg'
            #cv2.imwrite('image_ru_thresh' + str(count_ru) + '.jpg', thresh)
            save_text_ru(image_to_scan, count_ru)
            count_ru += 1

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # Клавиша Esc
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё решение данной проблемы:
Алгоритм прост - Создаём слайдер с вызовом метода, который ничего не делает, а позицию слайдера читаем через getTrackbarPos и загружаем в нужную переменную. Выглядит это так:

```
# Создание Trackbar и установка дефолтного значения
cv2.createTrackbar('threshold par 1', root_window, 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('threshold par 1', root_window, 0)

# Считывание в цикле актуального значения на Trackbar 
# (эта строка должна быть в цикле, у меня это был цикл 
# while true, тк я постоянно обновлял изображение с камеры)
par = cv2.getTrackbarPos('threshold par 1', root_window)

# То, где применяются у меня полученные значения
cv2.threshold(gray, par, par2, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Метод nothing
def nothing(x):
    pass
```

Не уверен в том, что это истинно верное решение данной проблемы, однако на мой взгляд всё логично и правильно. Надеюсь, в будущем это кому-то поможет. Отдельное спасибо моему другу, который помог с этим разобраться <З

Полезные ссылки:

[Документация по Trackbar](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar)

[Похожий вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047296/cv2-createtrackbar-using-python)

[Еще один вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428108/python-and-opencv-how-can-i-make-a-slider-window-in-which-i-can-use-to-change)